# Pandas set_option - more than one option per line

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a stupid question, but....

when setting options after importing pandas I set them one at a time such as:

```
pd.set_option('max_rows',1000)
pd.set_option('notebook_repr_html',False)
```

Is there any way to try and combine them. I tried passing a list of options but no worky.

Not a biggy if there is only one way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a native way to do multiple options on one line. I guess you could do something like:

#### List comprehension

```
[pd.set_option(option, setting) for option, setting in [('max_rows', 1000), ('notebook_repr_html', False)]]
```

*but I wouldn't recommend doing that!*

#### Longhand (one command per row)

I think writing this longhand is easier to read, more concise, and more pythonic:

```
pd.set_option('max_rows',1000)
pd.set_option('notebook_repr_html',False)
```

Comment: The list comprehension is pretty neat. For brevity I'd rewrite as the shorter `[pd.set_option(opt, stg) for opt, stg in...]`

Answer (score 4):

[A couple of years later to the party....]

I know it is an old question, but I found myself often searching for this.

This is my solution based on [Andy Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902262)
 solution above. A little bit more readable and uses python 3.X dict.

```python
pd_options = {
'display.max_rows'    : 500,
'display.max_columns' : 500,
'display.width'       : 1000,
}

[pd.set_option(option, setting) for option, setting in pd_options.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another couple of years later...]

There seems to be an undocumented feature:

```py
pd.set_option(
    'display.max_columns', 400,
    'display.width', 800)
print(pd.get_option('display.max_columns'))
print(pd.get_option('display.width'), '\n')

pd.set_option(
    'display.max_columns', 500,
    'display.width', 1000)
print(pd.get_option('display.max_columns'))
print(pd.get_option('display.width'), '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
400
800

500
1000
```