# Pandas can't print untruncated dataframe even with pd.set_option()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

all. I would like to type the whole pandas dataframe without trunction.
I wrote

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None,'display.width',None,'display.max_colwidth',-1)
```

but the output is still like this with \ and the information of a row is actualy not in a line. How to deal with this?
Thanks!
(look at the pic below)
[image: pic]

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900670/pandas-set-option-more-than-one-option-per-line/15902262) to be very helpful. You can't set it all at once, you can set it in comprehension.

Comment: Hi, even when I print those pd.set_options() seperately, the output is still as shown in the picture.

Comment: Is it the same if I specify an integer instead of None?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Isn't the setting enabled, but the browser's display range is just too small? Are you now in full screen mode?

Comment: `pd.options.display.max_columns = 100` So this is how it's set up.

Comment: `pd.options.display.width = 200`So this is how it's set up.

Comment: If you add display.width as None, it will not display the whole image.

Comment: Hi, but in this way, the values are seperated by space(because they are neat，some space have 3 blanks and some have 4 or 5), how could I print this table seperated by tab.

Comment: OK, I know. I only need to save my file using `w.to_csv("real.bed",sep="\t")`